# Check if user has enabled GPS after prompted

Tags: android, gps, location, locationmanager

Plain and simple. I start an Activity and check if the phone has the GPS module enabled or not. If it isn't enabled, I prompt the user with a dialog and ask if he wants to manually enable it. On Yes I activate the Settings for Location. Now the user can enable it if he wants to, but I need to check what he has done.

```
try {
    isGPSEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
} catch (Exception ex) {}
if (isGPSEnabled) {
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListenerGps);
} else {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage(
            "Your GPS module is disabled. Would you like to enable it ?")
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton("Yes",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            // Sent user to GPS settings screen
                            final ComponentName toLaunch = new ComponentName(
                                    "com.android.settings",
                                    "com.android.settings.SecuritySettings");
                            final Intent intent = new Intent(
                                    Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
                            intent.setComponent(toLaunch);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton("No",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

I need to know what the user has chosen in Location settings, when he comes back in order to proceed with my logic in code. Basically I need to wait for the user to make a choice and return to my activity, and also to recheck the status of gps module again.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Why not just check `LocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)` in your `onActivityResult()` method? When the user returns, this method should be called because you called `startActivityForResult()`. If the user has enabled GPS then `isProviderEnabled()` should now return a different result.

Alternatively, always do the GPS check in your onResume method. If the user returns from the Location settings and hasn't enabled GPS, then they will simply receive the same prompt until GPS *is* enabled.

Or am I missing something?

Comment: With the code as I wrote above, the onActivityResults fires immediately after starting the Settings intent... so it doesn't wait for the user to do his actions. Weird behavior but I've watched it with debugger.

Comment: Curiously starting the Settings intent with:     startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 0);
make onActivityResult trigger correctly

Comment: Maybe it was the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK that was preventing the behaviour you required.

Comment: Yes, your missing your common sense. It would be totally logical that setting activity would provide a result code.